# How can I get all my photos from Facebook with PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Facebook and PHP and so far I managed to connect to Facebook session + permissions, and even to get the logged in user profile picture.

question si : how can I get all of the logged in user photos and pick one randomized one?

thanks

Comment: Please only ask your question once. You've asked it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286184/how-can-i-get-all-my-photos-from-facebook-with-php-sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$facebook->api('https://graph.facebook.com/{your_user}/photos?access_token=...');
```

this is the api for getting photos from the user.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the FQL `photo` and `album` tables:

```
SELECT src_big
FROM photo
WHERE aid IN (
    SELECT aid
    FROM album
    WHERE owner=me()
)
```

And using the [PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/):

```
$facebook->api(array(
    'method'    => 'fql.query',
    'query'     => 'SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me())'
));
```

You can also test the above query in the [`fql.query` console](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/).