# Where can I find some great facebook Picture graph/ FQL Api examples? (Besides the wine book thing)

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to learn how I can get all of a user's pictures loaded into an array.(Maybe with the PHP sdk?) I'm new to FQL and the facebook API. Someone please help!

Comment: why are you going for fql? you should use php with graph api. its easier. tell me clearly what kindof help do u need?

Comment: I am completely new to this so I need this pretty broken down. I am trying to get the urls of all pictures that a user has and save the pictures on my server with PHP. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get all my photos from Facebook with PHP SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288068/how-can-i-get-all-my-photos-from-facebook-with-php-sdk)

Comment: Please use the search functionality next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting every album that a user has created is by this (using the PHPSDK);

```
$albums = $FB->api('/me/albums');
```

The reference for this is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

$albums will contain the fields located here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

So you can loop through $albums['data'] and get the list of Photo's for each album

```
$album = $FB->api('/'.$albums['data'][loop_increment]['id']);
```

What you get back is essentially an array with these elements: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Then it's just straight PHP to amalgamate all the elements into a single array.